# How to extract the content of specific html tags with scrapy or beautiful soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am making a toy crawler of this [site](http://quotes.toscrape.com/) in order to improve with scrapy. Thus, in the scrapy shell I tried:

```
In [1]: for e in response.css('meta.keywords').extract():
    ...:     print(e)

Out:

<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="abilities,choices">
<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="inspirational,life,live,miracle,miracles">
<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="aliteracy,books,classic,humor">
<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="be-yourself,inspirational">
<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="adulthood,success,value">
<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="life,love">
<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="edison,failure,inspirational,paraphrased">
<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="misattributed-eleanor-roosevelt">
<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="humor,obvious,simile">
```

With beautiful soup or scrapy how can I get the content of each `meta`?.

Comment: Simply use `e.content`.

Comment: what do you use? Scrapy or beautifulsoup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do it in one go by adjusting your selector:

```
for e in response.css('meta.keywords::attr(content)').extract():
    print(e)
```

Note that `attr` is a non-standard [custom selector](http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1) added by Scrapy itself.